# GestureDetector does not receive events while scrolling

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector, flutter-listview, flutter-onpressed

I have a ListView where each item has its own onTap event. If I tap on an item while the list is idle (not scrolling), everything works fine, but if I tap an item immediately following a scroll motion, the GestureDetector doesn't receive anything, which makes the app feel unresponsive for users navigating quickly. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

```
class _ScrollClickTestPageState extends State<ScrollClickTestPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Test"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 20,
        itemBuilder: (context,index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
            onTap: () => print("test: click detected"),
            child: Container(
              width: double.maxFinite,
              height: 200,
              color: ([...Colors.primaries]..shuffle()).first,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  '$index',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have working model for this issue:
Try below code:
**Replace** your   `onTap: () => print("test: click detected")`
with `onTap: () => {print("test: click detected")}`
And boom your tap Gesture is working.

Comment: No, I still get the same issue as the code I originally posted. Tap is received if listview is not scrolling, but ignored if it's scrolling.

Comment: So i don't think that this actually happens normally in any app. Bcz at a time only one gesture  works.

Comment: You're right, even native iOS and Android apps seem to have the same behavior. That's just how scrollables work I suppose.